# Calculating Tenure with Dynamic

Tags: reporting-services

I am attempting to calculate a dynamic tenure field in an SSRS report.  If the employee has been employed less than a month then display the tenure in days, if employed less than a year then display the tenure in months, then finally display the tenure in years.  I have an employee that was hired on 10/31/2016 and is currently displaying a tenure of 2 years.  My expression is listed below.  Can anyone point out my flaw on this one?  It looks right to me.

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Month,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now())<1, 
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) & " Days",
IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Year,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now())<1, 
DateDiff(DateInterval.Month,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) & " Months",
DateDiff(DateInterval.Year,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) & " Years"))
```

Comment: I've not tested this but when you compare the dates  in Years I suspect its returning a value 1 higher than you expected. You could change your <1 year check to be <12 months.

I would also add some temporary textboxes to the report showing each part of your expression so you can see whats going on.

I would also consider using SWITCH instead of nested IIF's to but that's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateDiff` does not work exactly how you think it does. `DateDiff(DateInterval.Year,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now())` is evaluating to 2, as you discovered, since it is comparing 2018 to the hire date of 2016. You can check this by replacing `Now()` with the dates 12/31/2017 and 1/1/2018 - the former will return 1 and the latter will return 2. This works similarly in the first part of your `IIf` where you are checking months: that evaluates to 16 when it has really only been 15 months and a few days. Essentially, `DateDiff` rounds whatever the decimal result is up to the next int.

The way you resolve this will ultimately depend on exactly what your requirements are: can you define a month as 30 days and a year as 365 days? Or is it important to consider that some months have more/less days, and some years are leap years?

If you can assume 30 day months and 365 day years, then you could use something like the following (also, I would recommend using `Switch` for this, since you have more than 2 possible outcomes - cleaner and easier to read in my opinion)

```
=Switch(
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) < 30, DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) & " Days",
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) < 365, DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) / 30 & " Months",
    true, DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!ASSC_HIRE_DATE.Value,Now()) / 365 & " Years"
)
```

If you want to also make this round down (for example, someone with a hire date of 10/31/2016 would not display as having a tenure of 2 years until 10/31/2018, instead of allowing the cell formatting to round 1.5 years up to 2), you can wrap the entire `Switch` statement in a `Floor` function.